# Using BS, looping over tags when line is missing from some iterations python3

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BS to select items with span-name*=nv tags. However, there are up to 2 'span' lines (i want the second) and when that 2nd line is missing, instead of just passing over the missing line, my loop returns an indexing error.

How can I tell my loop to pass over the missing lines and just return when my index exists?

https://www.imdb.com/list/ls047677021/

---

The below works.  However, if I change the index from 0 to 1 (which is what I need) i get an index error.  I get why i receive an error, but I don't get how I can work around it.

```
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.imdb.com/list/ls047677021/').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')


gross=[]

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='lister-item mode-detail'):
    money = div.select('span[name*=nv]')[0]['data-value']
    gross.append(money)

gross
```

---

```
gross=[]

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='lister-item mode-detail'):
    money = div.select('span[name*=nv]')[1]['data-value']
    gross.append(money)

 gross
```

**Error**:

---

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-67c1c65a2cce> in <module>
      2 
      3 for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='lister-item mode-detail'):
----> 4     money = div.select('span[name*=nv]')[1]['data-value']
      5     gross.append(money)
      6 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

https://www.imdb.com/list/ls047677021/

i should be getting a list of values in a dictionary. Instead I get either an error (or if I change the index) or the wrong data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: This is using Beautiful Soup 4.7+.

Personally, I would narrow down your select a bit more. You can actually target just the one you need with a little better selector.  Then you can use `select_one` which will return just the element you want. Then you can check if you got it by seeing if it is `None` (meaning you don't have it).

You can get this is a couple of ways. First I'll show you using a new feature in CSS level 4: `:nth-child(an+b of s)`. This will select the second span that matches your selector. https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/#:nth-child.

CSS spec: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-nth-child-pseudo

```
gross=[]

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='lister-item mode-detail'):
    el = div.select_one(':nth-child(2 of span[name*=nv])')
    if el is not None:
        gross.append(el['data-value'])

print(gross)
```

Or you can use the custom `:contains` pseudo-class to target the span following the span with `Gross:`. https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/#:contains.

```
gross=[]

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='lister-item mode-detail'):
    el = div.select_one('span:contains("Gross:") + span[name*=nv]')
    if el is not None:
        gross.append(el['data-value'])

print(gross)
```

Output:

```
['678,815,482', '700,059,566', '324,591,735', '417,719,760', '145,443,742', '213,515,506', '220,159,104', '137,690,172', '608,581,744', '216,210,777', '216,648,740', '213,767,512', '188,024,361', '51,024,708', '159,555,901', '215,288,866', '117,443,149', '159,342,015', '139,377,762', '120,634,935', '32,732,301', '57,421,715', '46,874,505', '174,532,921', '44,069,456', '335,061,807', '53,542,417', '99,345,950', '59,185,715', '102,084,362', '50,072,235', '69,001,013', '18,095,701', '100,407,760', '44,936,545', '48,686,605', '67,796,355', '54,547,470', '30,014,539', '69,086,325', '17,839,115', '81,903,458', '100,478,608', '99,215,042', '59,839,515', '2,474,044', '167,510,016', '21,704,844', '44,947,622', '115,715,889', '36,108,758', '28,780,744', '11,871,365', '48,795,601', '45,495,662', '1,214,525', '40,826,341', '40,717,020', '32,015,231', '21,023,275', '270,620,950', '33,562,069', '29,819,114', '35,851,379', '34,017,028', '30,824,628', '58,032,443', '50,316,123', '36,343,858', '201,089,881', '31,445,012', '42,402,632', '54,858,851', '171,956,231', '30,569,484', '26,020,957', '14,841,338', '127,195,589', '42,469,946', '30,617,396', '2,523,610', '20,706,452', '6,708,147', '9,227,130', '67,347,895', '52,856,061', '115,253,424', '68,549,695', '77,339,130', '68,566,296']
```

---

For Beautiful Soup 4.6 and below, you can install Beautiful Soup's new selector library separately and use it even though it isn't integrated in 4.6. Simply install via `pip`: `pip install soupsieve`.

```
import soupsieve as sv

gross=[]

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='lister-item mode-detail'):
    el = sv.select_one(':nth-child(2 of span[name*=nv])', div)
    if el is not None:
        gross.append(el['data-value'])

print(gross)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Read and understand what you are doing, but I'm getting error..."NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type."  when i use the above code using the :contains method for select_one. it looks like when you run it, you don't get that error. Any ideas why?

Comment: You would need to upgrade to Beautiful Soup 4.7. `pip install -U beautifulsoup4`. Apologies for not mentioning the version I was using.

Comment: I've updated the post to show how to get the same behavior in Beautiful Soup 4.6 and below. The new CSS selector library in 4.7 is also a stand alone library that should work in older Beautiful Soup versions if you use it's API directly.

Comment: This worked.  Thanks so much, i learned a lot and was able to solve this problem. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

you index error is because you haven't select() that data you think you have. your span tag just doesn't catch everything. i would use the find() function to find a parent container and then loop through the tags to get what you want to then use select() function, your span select simply doesnt not match the tags you want, test it before questioning it